# Why does my simple hello world C++ app use 3 threads?

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

When I look in windows task manage it says it's using 3 threads? Why is this? I was expecting just 1 thread to be used.

I used Netbeans IDE and MinGW-Windows g++ to compile it.

Thanks

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World";

    int input;
    cin >> input;

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: This is a question about netbeans, not C++. And are you sure you don't mean processes?

Comment: No it's about c++. I compile using MinGW's g++. Run the program by double clicking the .exe and the thread count in Windows Task Manager is 3.

Comment: Are you running your program using the Netbeans IDE/debugger, or, as a stand-alone program from the command-line?

Comment: Your code, compiled and run on the command line, shows 1 thread running belonging to the compiled file a.exe. The issue is entirely to do with Netbeans.

Comment: @CppNewbie: as an experiment, try redoing the program without involving Netbeans at all. That is, open a brand new CPP file in, say, Notepad, copy the code in the question into the file, save it, compile it using MinGW, run it by double-clicking the EXE, and see if you still see 3 threads.

Comment: Or to your thread monitoring tool, or your reading if it.

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED FOR EXPERIMENT - a MinGW console program that does not explicitly spawn threads will have only a single thread of execution.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Well, if an experiment is what it takes to convince the OP, then ... just do it!

Comment: @Neil: It might be more convincing for the OP if he does it himself. :)

Comment: Can any one of the people here confirm that a MinGW console  application, run from the command line, uses more than one thread itself? If you can't, please do not upvote stupid comments, make stupid comments or otherwise contribute in an uninformed manner - no one needs your opinions.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Your points certainly make sense. Still, the OP sees or believes that there are 3 "threads". We should help to clarify the misunderstanding or figure out whether it is related to Netbeans as good as we can. Simply restating facts or shouting in uppercase is not too helpful.

Comment: @Neil: I completely agree with you - the app will run in one thread alone. All I am saying is that one way of convincing the OP that you are right is to let him discover this himself.

Comment: @0xA3 Neither will making comments like yours. How about compiling the code, running it and seeing how many threads are actually used. which is what I, alone here it seems, have done. Sometimes, I feel like I am the only person in the world that owns a C++ compiler. Sheesh.

Comment: ''Hypothetically'' speaking, a "simple" Hello World console application could have more than one thread. The CRT initialization code, that runs before `main()` and calls it can create thousands of thread. There's no restriction on it. I think MSVCRT actually does create "extra" threads.


@CppNewbie: Can you provide access to your binary?

Comment: Have you choosed to build console or GUI application?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I can confirm that MinGW console application uses no more than one thread.

Comment: @CppNewbie: I wouldn't try to correct @Neil if my name was CppNewbie

Comment: @CppNewbie: Can you possibly show a build log which contains the command line used to compile your source file and a screenshot showing how many threads are used? This would certainly help analyzing your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe Netbeans put some wrapper for internal purpose ? (debugging, profilling, ...) Anyway it don't matter because you didn't create it : these threads should not interfere with your program and your program will not interfere with them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Task Manager or Netbeans, but can I suggest you may have misread the output:

- one thread to start a shell
- one thread for the shell to execute your program
- one thread for your program's executable

Total 3. None except the last  have anything to do with C++.

Comment: @Billy But we have no idea how the OP is interpreting this information.  Using Process Explorer I can interpret the executable as using 5 threads (the total of the process tree), when it is actually (as it always will) only be using one.